# Trouble creating ISO files from only certain DVDs

Tags: dvd, iso-image

I'm in the middle of trying to digitally convert all my DVDs and I've run across a curious issue - when creating ISO files, certain discs won't create the ISO file. I want to maintain the perfect 1:1 copy with menus, chapter selection, etc. so I don't want to rip to another format (which DOES work just fine on these discs). The DVDs play fine in both a DVD player and also in the drive I'm using to create ISO files - but about 1 out of every 12 just will not create an ISO file.  When I attempt to create the ISO file it instantly pops up the "completed" box instead of going through the 15min or so process of creating the ISO. There's no error message or anything.  All discs are region 1.  I'm currently using Wonderfox to create the ISO files but I tried using Imgburn and that wouldn't create an ISO either.  Bizarre?  I haven't been able to find anything online about this phenomenon either. Any thoughts?  (I haven't started working on Blu-ray discs yet. these are all dvds so far)

Comment: If they have copy protection, this is why.

Comment: So cheap $5 walmart specials (the bulk of the ones that won't create ISO files) won't work but stuff like the Deluxe Avatar box set and all of the Disney discs create ISO files just fine? I would have thought the bigger releases and especially Disney movies (so far Lion King, Aladdin, Anastasia) would have run across that sort of issue before some random walmart bargain bin copy of Army of Darkness (which is one of the ones that won't work).

Comment: I have run into this before on cheapo's, assumed it was some sort of copy protection. Put it in the drive and see if you can just copy the files off into a folder.

Comment: Update: Interestingly enough, on a whim I decided to try making an ISO from the troublesome discs while sitting on my laptop (I was using a couple desktops before) and now about half of the discs that wouldn't create the ISO file will do so just fine from my laptop - still using the same external reader as was plugged into one of my desktops.  Ha! no idea what's really causing this issue.  I tried again to create the ISO on my desktop and it still won't work but yeah, about half of them will work if I complete the process on this laptop instead. Twilight Zone!